# Is the convergence of solution ok in Fluent?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

I am simulating an axial turbine by using Fluent. The convergence of solution is monitored by checking the residuals of the numerically solved governing equations. Moreover, in order to judge the convergence, the behaviour of other quantities, such as the total pressure at the inlet and outlet boundaries, and torque coefficient generated by the rotor, are also monitored. Here, the default convergence criterion of each residual is reduced in order to allow the monitored quantities to stagnate at consistent values.

Now, according the following figures, Is the convergence of solution ok? and particularly about residuals? As you see in sixth figure, residuals increase and decrease!!! I want to know that this event is logical or not. I already thought that residuals should decrease decidedly because of convergence. But in this simulation, residuals increases and decreases!! What is reason for this event?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] this question so that it explains exactly what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: 1) did you have other experiments with similar mesh topology and similar mesh sizes? Did they converge?

Comment: No, I'm currently doing this simulation.